# NullPointerException in notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am trying for last 19 hours to update the `listFragment` but can't able to get working with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I have visited a lot of thread on it but failed to make working it. I have a parent Fragment and inside this I have three `ListFragment`. The `ListFragment`s need to pass data among them and I am able to do this via `interface`. Information are being passed successfully. But the `ListView` is not updating. This is my trying code:

```
public class SubChaptersListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
                : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Chapter instance = CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < instance.subchapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(instance.subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), layout, items);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    // this function is invoked from another `fragment` and position is retrieved successfully
    public void updateList(int position) {
        Chapter instance = CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position);
        items.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < instance.subchapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(instance.subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // nullpointerException in this line
    }

}
```

**Edit**
Logcat

```
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at me.kaidul.uhunt.SubChaptersListFragment.updateList(SubChaptersListFragment.java:57)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at me.kaidul.uhunt.CompetitiveProgramming.onChapterSelected(CompetitiveProgramming.java:214)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at me.kaidul.uhunt.ChaptersListFragment.onListItemClick(ChaptersListFragment.java:60)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
08-13 18:33:30.670: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

This is how I called the fragment from parentFragment:

```
@Override
public void onChapterSelected(int position) {
    SubChaptersListFragment subChapterFrag = new SubChaptersListFragment();
    if ( subChapterFrag != null) {
        subChapterFrag.updateList(position);
    } else {

    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question. Take a look

Comment: I think your `mAdapter` equals null in this case. Plz check for null before calling notifyDataSetChanged() on it.

Comment: Some code example will be helpful :)

Comment: onCreate probably hasn't been called before updateList. Making it static would be a little bit better, but preferably you wouldn't have to expose this. Maybe check states in onResume or use a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is much deeper than a simple null pointer.

The symptom of your problem is that `mAdapter` is null when `updateList()` is called. The bigger problem is that SubChaptersListFragment hasn't been created when `CompetitiveProgramming.onChapterSelected()` calls `updateList()`.

You are likely making direct references from one fragment (ChaptersListFragment) to another (SubChaptersListFragment) without considering the lifecycle.

You need to make sure that the fragment is created and attached to an activity before making any calls to it. I would suggest using the activity's FragmentManager to check for the existence of a fragment and creating it if necessary.

Comment: Before invoking the `updateList()`, the ListView is showing in the fragment and the fragment is bind in the frameLayout. If the `onCreate()` was not created, how the listView was shown?

Comment: Perhaps you are holding onto a reference to a fragment that is no longer attached. You'll need to set up some breakpoints and check that `onCreate()` is being invoked before `updateList()`, and that they reference the same object.

Comment: Please take a look. These are all of my code
This is the parent Fragment: http://pastebin.com/ZEY9HC6v
This is the xml Layout: http://pastebin.com/jjdtKDD5
This is ChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/ptcHK02E
This is SubChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/TKWwWkj6

Comment: I created `Fragment` inside a method. Now I have created the `Fragment` globally and the `Fragment` instance is available to all and mAdapter is okay. Thanks for your hints!